# How can I make SpaceX API query params work?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm practicing with the SpaceX API and everything works instead of the query API call. It actually works but the params that I sent and response that I get isn't accurate, so it always returns 10 results no matter what limit I write.

```
const API = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4";
const params = {
  offset: 30,
  limit: 10,
};
return axios
  .post(`${API}/launches/query`, { params })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error("Error: ", e));
```

So I do get the response but the number of launches I get is always 10 no matter what LIMIT I set. Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong and what is my code missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SpaceX API](https://github.com/r-spacex/SpaceX-API/blob/master/docs/v4/launches/query.md), in order to filter requests, you have to add the following JSON structure to the request:

```
{
  "query": {},
  "options": {}
}
```

Currently you're missing the `"options"` from your request, and the API ignores your filter. As per that, you should modify your `post` call parameter to the following:

```
axios.post(`${API}/launches/query`, { options: params })...
```

Comment: Thanks so much you are totally correct. Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

as of v5 I used:

```js
const configFetch = {
  method: "post",
  url: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v5/launches/query",
  data: {
    query: {
      upcoming: true,
    },
    options: {
      limit: 1,
      sort: {
        flight_number: "asc",
      },
    },
  },
};
  
const queryFunction = async () => {
  return await axios(configFetch).then((res) => res.data);
};
```